# How do i fix 'TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object' error in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
      9         break
     10     else:
---> 11         result = pipeline(frame)
     12         cv2.imshow("Frame", result)
     13         key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
     <ipython-input-2-d9c587a1d603> in pipeline(image)


     90     ### Draw lines and return final image
     91     line_img = np.copy((image)*0)
---> 92     draw_lines(line_img, lines, thickness=10)
     93 
     94     line_img = region_of_interest(line_img, v)
 <ipython-input-2-d9c587a1d603> in draw_lines(image, lines, color, thickness)


     26 def draw_lines(image, lines, color=[255, 0, 0], thickness=4):
     27     for line in lines:
---> 28         for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
     29             cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, thickness)
     30
```

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object

I want to have coordinates of the beginning and end of the lane from lane list those coordinates are mentioned as x1, y1, x2, y2. And also when i printed the line it has 8 float numbers containing.

Comment: `x1, y1, x2, y2  = line` Unpack the line list into variables. Remove `for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
x1, y1, x2, y2  = line
```

Unpack the line list into variables. What happens under the hood is

```
(x1, y1, x2, y2) = (0, 0, 5, 5)
```

And hence

```
x1 = 0
y1 = 0 and so on...
```

Remove `for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line` loop.